# Why won't my JS function work properly?

Tags: javascript

I am very new to Javascript, so please pardon my lack of knowledge.
I am trying to use Javascript to find the slope of two data points (x1,y1)(x2,y2). The equation for the slope is m=y1-y2/x2-x1. Here is what I have done so far in JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1wvfz0ku/ 
The problem is that when I try to calculate the points only NaN appears.
Like I said I am very new at coding in JS, so I can't see where I have messed up in. Any help would be much appreciated! :-)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div style="width:250px;height:auto;margin:auto;">
<h1>Find the Slope of Two Data Points</h1>
<p>
Find the slope of two sets of points:
</p>
<var>M</var>=<p id="slope"></p>
Enter your points below:
<form id="points">
X<sub>1</sub>: <input type="text" id="x1"/><br/>
X<sub>2</sub>: <input type="text" id="x2"/><br/>
Y<sub>1</sub>: <input type="text" id="y1"/><br/>
Y<sub>2</sub>: <input type="text" id="y2"/><br/>
</form>
<script>
function findSlope() {
//The points//
var xOne = document.getElementById("x1").value;
var xTwo = document.getElementById("x2").value;
var yOne = document.getElementById("y1").value;
var yTwo = document.getElementById("y2").value;

//slope equation//
var op1 = yTwo - yOne;
var op2 = xTwo - xOne;
var answer = op1 / op2;
document.getElementById("slope").innerHTML = answer;
} 
function reset(){
document.getElementById("points","slope").reset();
}
</script>

<button type="submit" onClick="findSlope()">Find the Slope</button>
<button type="submit" onClick="reset()">Clear Points</button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me as is: http://jsbin.com/mokoya/1/edit?html,console,output

Comment: What browser are you testing in? *Shouldn't* matter, but this is the real world and if you're using <Insert bad browser here>, you're gonna have problems

Comment: I am using an old version of Chrome on a MacBook Pro from 2006. maybe that's why it wasn't working properly...

Answer (score 1):

This [works just fine](http://jsbin.com/mumuqimube/1) **unless** `xTwo - xTwo` is `0`, in which case you're trying to divide a number by `0`, which is defined in JavaScript to be `NaN`.

---

That said: The `value` property of elements is always a string. It just happens that all of the operations you've used (`-`, `/`) will implicitly convert from string to number, but if you'd used `+` you'd've gotten some very odd results indeed (because `+` with strings is concatenation, not addition). Better to explicitly ensure you're dealing with numbers, by using `parseInt(theString, 10)` (if you're dealing with decimal).

---

Example allowing for `xTwo - xOne` being `0` and parsing the inputs as decimal:

```js
function findSlope() {
  //The points//
  var xOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("x1").value, 10);
  var xTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById("x2").value, 10);
  var yOne = parseInt(document.getElementById("y1").value, 10);
  var yTwo = parseInt(document.getElementById("y2").value, 10);

  //slope equation//
  var op1 = yTwo - yOne;
  var op2 = xTwo - xOne;
  var answer = op2 === 0 ? "flat or whatever" : op1 / op2;
  document.getElementById("slope").innerHTML = answer;
} 

function reset(){
  document.getElementById("points","slope").reset();
}
```

```html
<div style="width:250px;height:auto;margin:auto;">
<h1>Find the Slope of Two Data Points</h1>
<p>
Find the slope of two sets of points:
</p>
<var>M</var>=<p id="slope"></p>
Enter your points below:
<form id="points">
X<sub>1</sub>: <input type="text" id="x1"/><br/>
X<sub>2</sub>: <input type="text" id="x2"/><br/>
Y<sub>1</sub>: <input type="text" id="y1"/><br/>
Y<sub>2</sub>: <input type="text" id="y2"/><br/>
</form>
<button type="submit" onClick="findSlope()">Find the Slope</button>
<button type="submit" onClick="reset()">Clear Points</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_number.asp Use code  x = Number(x) and do it for all variables